# Break value to seperated variable

Tags: shell-script

My idea is to break some value to the seperated variable. Below is example that script failed to get output as needed. Any suggestion for the idea?

```
A=12-13-14
IFS="-" read -p I J K <<<$A

echo Lin number is $I
echo Michele Number is $J
echo Gina number is $K
```

**my expected output is :**

```
Lin number is 12
Michele number is 13
Gina number is 14
```

Comment: `<<foo` is a here-doc. You want a here-string: `<<<`. And you gave no prompt text after `-p`.

Comment: i put string <<< and get below output. still didn't get as expected:
Lin number is <br/>
Michele Number is 12 13 14 <br/>
Gina number is <br/>

Comment: @ruslyislam [edit] your question to show the exact command you used. Don't put commands and their output in comments, the formatting just doesn't work

Comment: "And you gave no prompt text after `-p`"

Comment: can you explain more what is prompt text you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to possibly be using `bash` since you're using a "here-string" (`<<<`).  Additionally, in some other shells, `read -p` will read from a coprocess, which means your code would produce different results from what you say in comments. So it's most likely `bash`.

The `-p` option to the `read` utility in `bash` takes an option-argument.  This option-argument is a string that will be used as the interactive prompt when asking a user for a value.  In your code, that prompt will be the string `I`, while the variables `J` and `K` will be assigned data by `read` from standard input (your string `$A`).  This is why `$I` is an empty string when you `echo` it.

```
$ read -p 'Enter value: ' thing
Enter value: hello
$ printf '%s\n' "$thing"
hello
```

I assume you meant to use something like `-r` instead of `-p`:

```bash
A=12-13-14
IFS='-' read -r I J K <<<"$A"

printf 'Lin number is %s\n'     "$I"
printf 'Michele Number is %s\n' "$J"
printf 'Gina number is %s\n'    "$K"
```